# Unable to update empty array with formdata

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to store the data attached to buttons on the site when a user clicks on them. I am using onClick function to grab the data passed in from the button and I am attempting to set it in state.  The issue I am running into; however, is that the state value is not updating for whatever reason and it remains an empty array.
**My desired result**
if the object exists in the array, update it.  If it does not, append to the array.  Any guidance as to why state is not updating properly would be greatly appreciated.  My code is as follows:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
  const data = [
    { name: "test1", id: 1, isActive: false },
    { name: "test2", id: 2, isActive: false }
  ];

  const handleClick = (item) => {
    setFormData(
      (formData) =>
        formData.map((res) =>
          res?.id === item.id
            ? { ...res, checked: !res.isActive }
            : { ...item, checked: !item.isActive }
        )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => {
        return <button onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>{item.name}</button>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

attached is a code sandbox for debugging: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sun-20ec0?file=/src/App.js:0-681

Comment: What code would set formData to something other than an empty array?

Comment: the handleclick function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you are initializing `formData` to be an empty array. This makes the `map` call on `formData` in `handleClick` do nothing, because calling map on an empty array will not call the map function on any elements.

Comment: do you have a solution on how to fix this

Comment: useState takes the initial state as it's only parameter. You should pass in an array of `form` objects or whatever you want to update as the initial state

Comment: much appreciated